# T2200 when you own your house

Tags: income-tax, canada

I work from home in Canada. My workplace issues a T2200 acknowledging this fact. I am an employee, not a contractor.

If I rented my place, I could write off an appropriate fraction of my rent. That is, if I used 1/4 of my square footage exclusively for work, I could write off 1/4 of my rent. I think I could also write off a similar proportion of expenses such as heating and electricity (though not Internet).

However, I do not rent. I own my home. My question, then, is what I can reasonably write off using the T2200. If I had a mortgage, could I write off any of that? Perhaps just the interest? I don't actually have a mortgage; does that mean I have to pay more tax compared to someone who rents? Can I still write off a fraction of my heating and electricity?

Answer (score 4):

The Canada Revenue Agency [addresses this](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/ncm-tx/rtrn/cmpltng/ddctns/lns206-236/229/slry/wrkspc-eng.html).

You cannot deduct mortgage interest, property taxes, or home insurance. You also cannot deduct your mortgage itself.

You can deduct rent, presumably because rent is an expense.

Whether renting or owning the workspace, you can deduct maintenance costs on a reasonable basis. For example, if your workspace is 1/4 of the total space of the home, you could deduct 1/4 of the electricity and heating bills. If you repainted the workspace, you could deduct 100% of those costs. If you pay someone to clean your house, you could deduct 1/4 of those expenses.

It's a bit more complicated if the 1/4 of the space used for work is also used for non-work-related activities.

This does indeed mean that you pay lower taxes if you rent, as you can write off a proportion of your rent.

Comment: Good answer. I deleted mine, since yours is better.